# JSONP request fails when https is used instead of http

Tags: jquery, api, google-app-engine, jsonp

I have an API client which makes a JSONP request using JQuery. Everything works fine
when this API client's not using SSL however fails when the SSL is used.

For example I have a URL **http://apiclient.com** and I am making following JSONP request from this domain:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data)
    {
        $.each(data.services, function(index, service) {
            processService(service);
        });
    }
});
```

I see an appropriate request made to API host specified in the url and callback function in **success** is properly called with properly formatted data passed onto it.

However when I change above URL of the API client to **https://apiclient.com**, 
no request is observed at API host. I see no errors in either side of the logs.

Note: only difference is **http** to **https** on API client side.

Do you need to handle JSONP request differently when using https domain?

Thanks.

Edit:
This issue is only observed with Chrome. It works with Firefox and Safari. 
However I got a quick warning on FireFox asking I am about to make unencrypted request from
encrypted site. I allowed it and never saw the warning again.

Comment: Is your server configured to accept the Https requests? To your ajax query, add an error function as well and check if you get any errors.

Comment: Can you call the https API URL normally? Maybe there's a certificate error or something?

Comment: @ryadavilli no AJAX error handler for `jsonp` requests.. see docs **Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests.**

Comment: @charlietfl Ahh yes, you are correct. My mistake on that.

Comment: Well, the *first step* is finding out what the *real* issue is. I would suggest using a tool like fiddler2 (although firebug/developer tools are sufficient to see the error codes I believe) to see *what is sent* and *what is returned*.

Comment: Here's a hint on what may cause this problem: http://ithemes.com/codex/page/Fix_Non-SSL_Elements_on_SSL_Page. I'd guess you're trying to access the secure site while you're page actually is running non-secure?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a solution. Problem was that JQuery and other resources were imported from non-secure sites. Solution was to reference from https.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any different in JSONP request for http and https.

Try us .getJSON instead:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  $.each(data.services, function(index, service) {
        processService(service);
    });
});
```

Using jQuery.ajax() will cause cross-browser issue but not the case with jQuery.getJSON()
Look at jQuery site for more info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

There's similar post with this issue: [JSONP To Acquire JSON From HTTPS Protocol with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780702/jsonp-to-acquire-json-from-https-protocol-with-jquery)

Comment: $.getJSON is short hand for $.ajax, so the behavior is identical.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the protocol is the same effect as changing any other part of the URL -- it will trigger a violation of the same-origin policy and force you into cross-domain mode. If you already have cross-domain access working, it will continue to work with https as well as it did with http.

you can use getJSON for example

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
  $('.result').html('<p>' + data.foo + '</p>'
    + '<p>' + data.baz[1] + '</p>');
});
```

check complete getJSON documentation http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

will i was wrong ... using Juqery.ajax will cause cross-browser issue but not with Jquery.getJSON

http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getJSON_.28using_JSONP.29

here is an example of cross-domain get JSON

firefox has a problem with HTTPS, as i know it will be fixed if you send your request like this

```
$.getJSON('ajax/test.json',{}, function(data) {
  $('.result').html('<p>' + data.foo + '</p>'
    + '<p>' + data.baz[1] + '</p>');
});
```

soruce [AJAX https POST requests using jquery fail in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597073/ajax-https-post-requests-using-jquery-fail-in-firefox)

i hope this helps

Comment: First in my case its all working without http and does not work with https. So Same origin policy is not an issue here, and I am using GET not POST. I believe $.getJSON is just a short hand for $.ajax as stated in documentation. Your solution does not solve the problem.

Comment: I think what could be the problem is the data being returned for HTTP and HTTPS are not the same. If that's the case, try to get the URL from fiddler, specifying the Content-Type as application/json, using both HTTP and HTTPS protocols. Then, compare the result from both protocols.