# getJSON works cross domain, but not on same domain/locally

Tags: jquery, json, .htaccess

I'm trying to use `jQuery.getJSON` to get read in a simple JSON file and access the data within it. For testing purposes, I was hosting the .json file on dropbox and calling it like this:

example.com/blah/**foo.js**

```
jQuery.getJSON("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/blah/data.json", function(data) {

    values = data.A;
});
```

dropbox.com/blah/**data.json**

```
{
"A": {
    "va1":"Value 1a",
    "va2":"Value 2a",
    "va3":"Value 3a",
    },
"B": {
    "vb1":"Value 1b",
    "vb2":"Value 2b",
    "vb3":"Value 3b",
    },
}
```

This works fine and `values` is what I expect it to be. But when I try to store the .json file on the same webhost (`example.com/blah/data.json`) as the javascript file, and access it like this, `values` is empty:

example.com/blah/**bar.js**

```
jQuery.getJSON("https://example.com/blah/data.json", function(data) {
//jQuery.getJSON("./data.json", function(data) { // tried relative links as well...

    values = data.A;
});
```

Following the advice about setting the MIME type in my `.htaccess` file like so,

example.com/**.htaccess**

```
AddType application/json .json
```

But it will still not load the contents of the JSON file at all. The link to the json file on my host is correct (it brings up the json file when pasted into the browser). I don't understand this as usually getJSON problems relate to cross-domain issues, but here I get problems when accessing a .json file on the *same* domain, and cross-domain appears to be working fine.

Comment: The URL of the page containing your JavaScript code (the code that calls `.getJSON()`) has to have *exactly* the same domain; that is, the page URL needs to start with `https://example.com/`. Is that the case here?

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you taken? Just saying it doesn't work doesn't provide much information. Inspect the actual request in dev tools network for clues. Do some console logging and json validation as well

Comment: Try chaining `.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)})` to `$.getJSON()`

Comment: Use a relative path if its hosted on the same domain. Save yourself some headaches.

Comment: @Pointy, @guest271314,  thanks - you've pointed me in the right direction here. It was a case of ``https://`` vs ``http://``. Both are valid domains on my site, but I was calling it from the http:// version of my site. It's odd though because I would expect the ``https://dropbox...`` to fail as well, but it doesn't. (see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133484/jsonp-request-fails-when-https-is-used-instead-of-http)

Comment: @decvalts well dropbox must be returning the proper cross-origin headers, so the browser allows the call to happen.